# Maven can not calculate build path in Eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

I am very new to using Maven, and I'm trying to follow along with an online tutorial using Eclipse, however when I'm writing the Maven file, I get the following Error:

```
CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.8.1: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.8.1 from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.8.1 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Failed to transfer http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.8.1/maven-compiler-plugin-3.8.1.pom. Error code 501, HTTPS Required
```

My pom.xml looks like this, and the plugin tag is underlined with a red error

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.pluralsight</groupId>
  <artifactId>conference</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

I've tried deleting the repository folder in my .m2 folder, and updating my project, but I haven't found any fix yet. Can someone help me out?

Comment: There should be a settings.xml file in .m2 directory that defines which repos you pull from, that may be incorrectly configured based on the fact that your error message is a failed pull from maven repo.

Comment: I don't actually see a settings.xml file in my .m2 directory

Comment: You are using http access instead of https this is the issue....

Comment: Have you checked on plain command line? Furthermore the most recent version of Apache Maven is 3.6.3 see https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

Comment: I downloaded 3.6.0, and tried 'mvn --version' in the command line, and I'm getting the error: "Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher"

Answer (score 1):

Your Maven versions is probably out of date.
Newer versions should automatically go to the central maven repo using HTTPS.

Your error is saying: Error code 501, HTTPS Required
When trying to go to the central repo.

Update maven to the latest version or atleast to 3.2.3.

Download the latest Maven version from: https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

In Eclipse you can change the maven version like this:

```
Preferences -> Maven -> Installations -> Add...

Now select the Maven you just installated
```

Comment: What IDE / operation system are you using? Are you building in an IDE or on the command line?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse

Comment: I have added it to my answer

Comment: @JonahDowns The current Eclipse version contains the latest Maven 3.6.3. Obviously, you are using an outdated Eclipse version. To update the embedded Maven, upgrade Eclipse.

Comment: Upgrading eclipse didn't seem to fix the problem.